# SwiperJS Thumbs bug

Tags: swiper.js

Created a swipe with thumbs. When I click on thumbs, it scrolls to the right with incomprehensible logic. I cannot understand what this may be connected with, I am trying to solve this problem for the second day, nothing comes out. Is it possible to somehow disable this option so that you can remove this scroll when clicked?

```js
const productThumbs = new Swiper(".swiper-thumbs", {
        spaceBetween: 30,
                loop: true,
                slidesPerView: 6,
                loopedSlides: 7,
});
const productCarousel = new Swiper(".swiper-content", {
                effect: 'fade',
                fadeEffect: {
                    crossFade: true
                },
                touchRatio: 0,
    thumbs: {
        swiper: productThumbs,
    }
});
```

```css
.swiper-slide{
    background: gray;
}
.swiper-thumbs .swiper-slide{
    height: 300px;
} 
.swiper-content{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.swiper-thumbs .swiper-slide{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.swiper-content .swiper-slide{
    height: 250px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 72px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="swiper-container swiper-thumbs">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">01</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">02</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">03</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">04</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">05</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <span class="slider-title">06</span>
            <img src='https://i.ibb.co/Tq5Hvp8/1.png'>
                    <span class="slider-desc">Windows Server</span>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>
<div class="swiper-container swiper-content">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
                <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do this, but I just simply do not understand why this is happening

Answer (score -2):

In the "thumbs" slider, you need to change the value "loop" to "false" or remove the key "loop" from "thumbs" slider.